# SharePoint search results web part dont show null

Tags: search, search-results, people-search

I am wondering if anyone could help please. I have a search results web part that is showing only users, however I need to shows users if the Department is not null. I have tried using:

> -Department: " " 
>   -Department= ""

Either of the above have not worked and null is not available as a parameter in the query editor tool.

Any help  would be appreciated.